# sql statement syntax for search

Tags: php, mysql, where-clause

I would like to write an sql statement for search. Here is sample database structure.
[image]

For eg, I want to display all records with topic `'13'`. How can i write sql query for searching 13 from the above structure? Any suggestions?

Can i able to use `WHERE Topic LIKE '%13%'`? Anything wrong with this?

Comment: SELECT * FROM yourtable WHERE topic LIKE '%13%'; ?

Comment: Yes. Lots wrong. See normalisation

Comment: You should really be normalizing your table first. But anyways, you can always use `LIKE` in your condition

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
SELECT * FROM `TABLE_NAME` WHERE `Topic` LIKE "%13%";
```

Comment: Well the asker doesn't specify what to expect in the column. This SQL would work for the data given in the example.

Answer (score 0):

It's better and faster to save it in a third table of many-to-many relationship.

If you want to save as per your example (single table), try to save data as eg ",10,13,15,"

always have coma before and after, thus the following sql will exclude 213 and 132 etc

```
select * from  table_name where Topic like '%,13,%'
```

Comment: I don't agree with adding a comma at the start just to make querying easier. If you had to get the data and then explode it in php for example, you will always have an empty value at the start of the array.

Answer (score -1):

```
select * from table where find_in_set("13",topic);
```

or if topic is not used as a set, you could do ...

```
select * from table where concat(",",topic) like "%,13,%";
```

The 2nd isn't real elegant but I've had to do that a couple times.

Because the data isn't really normalized, I used concat to add a comma to the topic field so I could make sure the "like" comparison would pass with a comma before and after the value.  I suppose we would also have to remove any unwanted spaces as well for this example, so ultimately it would end up like:

```
select * from TABLE where concat(",",replace(topic," ","")) like "%,13,%";
```

Ultimately, we have to know what to expect in the topic column to come up with a query that would always work.  In the past, I've had situations where I would add values to a string field (i.e. topic) with a delimiter before and after each value like:

```
(1)(2)(3)(14)(15)(255)(283)
```

If you did something like this for the topic field, the query is simple ...

```
select * from table where topic like "%(13)%";
```

Comment: Really?  A down vote for something that works?  Geeze.